# Kubernetes external DNS in split horizon and Service

Tags: kubernetes

I have multiple external-dns services doing a split horizon dns. I have 2 instances of external-dns managing the same domain name but one is a public zone and one is a private zone.

How do I tell a Kubernetes Service which instance to attach to?

This is currently how I have this written but it obviously won't work.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: myservice.mycorp.mydomain.com
```

Comment: Is your issue resolved? If yes, can you provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.

Answer (score 0):

*Split horizon* is basically a dynamic routing term, meaning countermeasure to prevent routing loops.

What you are describing is called *DNS views*. So far you have to point your naming services to a single instance of DNS, which will further provide DNS view based on the IP source address  of the caller.

Since most of the CNIs merely take the resolver from the host, it seems to be enough to just modify the resolv.conf accordingly.

Comment: It seems to be known as split-horizon DNS.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-horizon_DNS

Comment: Nope. It's not known by this nonsense. "*This article relies largely or entirely on a single source. (June 2009)*".

Comment: Microsoft call it Split-Brain and, prior to Server 2016, required more than one DNS Server (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/dns/deploy/split-brain-dns-deployment).  

DNS Views (from what I  can tell from Bind’s documentation) are Bind 9’s implementation of the same concept although ~16 years earlier.

It’s not uncommon for this to be implemented by different DNS servers configured to be authoritative for the same domain.

Comment: Also, feel free to edit/rename the Wikipedia article if you believe it’s nonsense (or tag it for review).

Comment: *Split-brain* is a common term indicating malfunction; their DNS server implemantation is a known mistake. No wonder it's called this way.

Comment: Split-horizon is also a common term that describes similar issues with routing and DNS (the former having no upside and the latter making configuration complicated).  Also, no need for the MS bashing in a respectful forum.